# Вывод ошибки Участник не найден

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    @commands.command(name = "give_val")
    @commands.has_any_role('┃Валькирия')
    async def give_role_clan(self, ctx, target: discord.Member):
        role = self.bot.get_guild(799717594693238784).get_role(837663413567750155)
        role2 = self.bot.get_guild(799717594693238784).get_role(837663298165407754)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await target.add_roles(role, role2)
        if MemberNotFound:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Кланы',
                description = 'Участник не найден!'
            ))

        else:
            await target.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Кланы',
                description = 'Добро пожаловать в клан **Валькирия!**',
                color = 0xff2929
            ))
```

Comment: Что за глобальная переменная `MemberNotFound`?

Comment: @gil9red, а это нужно как-то по другому указывать? .__.

Comment: Глобальные переменные это зло, а в асинхронном коде, зло в квадрате

Comment: @gil9red, а как тогда по другому сделать?

Comment: Для хранения данных лучше использовать базу данных

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать ивент on_command_error для ловли ошибок, которые происходят в команде, вот вам пример:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Кланы',
                description = 'Участник не найден!'
            ))
    else:
        raise error
```